# TCP Connections in Go

Tags: tcp, go, network-programming

Here is my code:

```
package main                                                                       

import (                                                                           
    "fmt"                                                                          
    "net"                                                                          
)                                                                                  

func main() {                                                                      
    addr, _ := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8081")                         
    listener, _ := net.ListenTCP("tcp", addr)                                      
    fmt.Printf("listener addr: %s\n", listener.Addr().String())                    
    for {                                                                          
        conn, err := listener.AcceptTCP()                                          
        if err != nil {                                                            
            // handle error                                                        
            fmt.Println("err")                                                     
            return                                                                 
        }                                                                          
        go handleConnection(conn)                                                  
    }                                                                              
}                                                                                  

func handleConnection(conn *net.TCPConn) {                                         
    fmt.Printf("conn addr: %s\n", conn.LocalAddr().String())                       
    fmt.Printf("conn remote addr: %s\n", conn.RemoteAddr().String())               
}
```

Output

```
listener addr: 127.0.0.1:8081
conn addr: 127.0.0.1:8081
conn remote addr: 127.0.0.1:1234
```

Why do `listener` and `conn` have the same address?  In TCP, I thought a new socket was created for new connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got me puzzled for a second, but this is correct. A new socket is indeed created (with a unique local+remote address tuple). This quote from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket#Socket_states_and_the_client-server_model) describes it pretty well:

> A server may create several concurrently established TCP sockets with the same local port number and local IP address, each mapped to its own server-child process, serving its own client process. They are treated as different sockets by the operating system, since the remote socket address (the client IP address and/or port number) are different; i.e. since they have different socket pair tuples.

If you think about it other way around, i.e. outgoing connection, you don't find it strange seeing remote address being the same across many sockets (e.g. `google.com:80`), so the same holds for incoming connections.

Probably a nice side effect of this is that tools like `netstat`, when inspecting sockets, are nicely showing the source port, instead of random pairs.

Answer (score 0):

No, your Listener is accepting connections in port 8081, so the `LocalAddr` is going to have that port. If you dial out to another server, you usually use a different port each time, though that's not required either.